# How does OR operator work in find function in javascript or typescript?

Tags: typescript

If I have an array of objects:

```
myArray = [
  {id:123, name:"abc"},
  {id:234, name:"xyz"},
  {id:345, name:"pqr"}
]

someValue = 123
someOtherObj = {id: 234}

let matchedObj = this.myArray.find(object=> object.id === somevalue || object.id === someOtherObj.id) 
console.log(matchedObj)
```

Would the output be 123 every time, or it could be 123 or 234? Can you explain how this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) finds the **first** matching entry in the array. `condition1 || condition2` is true if **either** `condition1` **or** `condition2` is true. (More specifically: `||` evaluates its left-hand operand first, and if that result is truthy, takes that truthy value as its result; if the left-hand result is falsy, `||` evaluates its right-hand operand and takes that value as its result.)

So with that sample data, it will always match the first entry, because it matches the condition and it's before the second entry (which also matches the condition). But if the entries were in a different order, where the `id: 234` were before the `id: 123`, it would find that one instead:

```js
const someValue = 123;
const someOtherObj = {id: 234};

function match(array) {
    console.log(array.find(object => object.id === someValue || object.id === someOtherObj.id));
}

match([
    {id:123, name:"abc"}, // Finds this one
    {id:234, name:"xyz"},
    {id:345, name:"pqr"}
]);
match([
    {id:345, name:"pqr"},
    {id:234, name:"xyz"}, // Finds this one
    {id:123, name:"abc"}
]);
```

Comment: T.J. Crowder thanks for answering. I guess the order of my array is the reason why I was getting 2nd match some time.